# vb.net set cell numeric format after cellendedit event

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have predefined columns in my `DataGridView`.
There are two editable columns and one read-only column.
I have set all columns format to numeric style from cellstyle builder

When I input some text into the two columns, the format won't change, but the read-only column do.

So I've added format change on `cellformatting` event like this

```
    Dim c As String
    If e.ColumnIndex = colHrg.Index _
        AndAlso e.Value IsNot Nothing AndAlso e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        c = e.Value.ToString
        e.Value = c
    End If
    e.CellStyle.Format = "N3"
```

But it seems the event is not fired, so I decided to add format styling on `cellendedit` event.
Yet, it still didn't worked

```
    dgv_beli.Columns("colHrg").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N3"
```

I've also tried `editingcontrolshowing` and `cellvaluechanged` event, but still not working

Can someone guide me how to fixed this. I've spent a lot of time to solved this, really curious to find a good solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add an event of EditingControlShowing
2. In EditingControlShowing, check that if the current cell lies in the desired column.
3. Register a new event of KeyPress in EditingControlShowing(if above condition is    true).
4. Remove any KeyPress event added previously in EditingControlShowing.
5. In KeyPress event, check that if key is not digit then cancel the input.

Example:

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender,  
DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
     e.Control.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(Column1_KeyPress);
     if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0) //Desired Column
     {
        TextBox tb = e.Control as TextBox;
        if (tb != null)
        {
            tb.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(Column1_KeyPress);
        }
    }
}

private void Column1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
    { 
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```